# Need to change the glyphicon using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

Need to change the glyphicon for collapese panel using angularjs, below is the which I have tried

```
<div class="panel-heading pan_hd1" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">
    Heading <span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right pan_arrow1': !isCollapsed, 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up pull-right pan_arrow1': isCollapsed}"></span>
</div>
```

Please help on this

Comment: glyghicon is not changing

Comment: `<span class="glyphicon pull-right pan_arrow1 glyphicon-menu-{{collapsed ? 'up' : 'down'}}"></span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the name of your var. The one use for class was `isCollapsed`, teh one change by `ng-click` was `collapsed`.

It's maybe also wrong in `ng-model` but to be honest, I can't fugure out what you are trying to save in your model.

```
<div class="panel-heading pan_hd1" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed">Heading<span  ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right pan_arrow1': !isCollapsed, 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up pull-right pan_arrow1': isCollapsed}"></span></div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dq7v6zp1/1/)

Comment: Yes now it is working thank you so much for your help

Comment: your code change icon but, collapse function will not work, once again thank for your help I got solution

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working

```
<div class="panel-heading pan_hd1" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Heading<span  ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right pan_arrow1': !collapsed, 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up pull-right pan_arrow1': collapsed}"></span></div>
```

Thanks for your help.